# Roman number not showing with \pageref

Tags: cross-referencing, page-numbering

I tried to use the `\pageref` to show page number when referencing to a figure/table, it works fine where I have arabic number but for the tables that appear in my appendix the numbers are not showing. I haven't used the package `appendix` and `\appendix` but `\pagenumbering{Roman}` before the appendix starts.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,french]{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{prettyref}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\maketitle

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\section{Section}
See figure \ref{tab:table} on page \pageref{tab:table}

\pagenumbering{Roman}
\section*{Appendix}

\begin{table}
\caption{caption}
\begin{tabularx}{10cm}{XXl}
.... table 
\end{tabularx}
\label{tab:table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a minimum working example(MWE) that generates the problem you're looking to solve. I'm afreid that your current description of the problem isn't quite enough to diagnose what's going on.

Comment: I don't know what I should copy/paste here because I have a huge preamble and I do not know which one is related to the page numbering except the `\pagenumbering` I wrote.

Comment: @esmitex You should be able to remove things while keeping the problem and end up with a file of a few lines you can post. If removing something fixes the problem then that is the culprit. See http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that#answer-3225

Comment: I believe it might have simply been some compiling bug that led to this error because I copied pasted the full code again in my doculent and the `pageref` is working with roman numbers now.

Comment: the style of page number for the first page is set when `\maketitle` is activated. the style of page numbers won't change until there's a new page.  so with the insertion of more material before the appendix (and the command `\pagenumbering{Roman}`), this will "fix itself".  this can be demonstrated by inserting `\clearpage` before the `\pagenumbering` command.